# Styling a geoJSON Feature Layer in MapBox

Tags: javascript, geojson, mapbox

I just started playing with MapBox and am running into a confusing issue. I'm creating a map with a geoJSON layer using this code:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', '<MapBoxID>');
            var zipLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer('data/blah.json');
            zipLayer.addTo(map);
            zipLayer.setStyle({color: 'red'});
```

The map appears and shows the geoJSON, but it ignores the styling. When I copy that last line into the JS console in my browser, it works fine, though.

What am I missing here? Also, I've tried at least a dozen different ways of including the style in the options directly in the featureLayer() call, but nothing has worked. How do I specify the style when creating the feature layer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing a bit here, since I don't know the Mapbox JS very well, but it sounds a lot like an async error. Strangely, I don't see anything in the Mapbox or Leaflet APIs about a callback for this function. But, you can pass straight GeoJSON to featureLayer(), so I'd suggest using jQuery (or your XHR library of choice) to grab the data:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', '<MapBoxID>');
var zipLayer;

$.getJSON('data/blah.json', function(data) {
    zipLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer(data);
    zipLayer.addTo(map);
    zipLayer.setStyle({color: 'red'});
});
```

Hopefully that'll do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, that works! Still confused what's going on here, though. Perhaps there is a better solution still.

Answer (score 3):

I would go the route of using the built-in featureLayer function, then listening for it to be ready. This should help get you pointed in the right direction:

```
var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
    .loadURL('/example-single.geojson')
    .on('ready', function(layer) {
        this.eachLayer(function(marker) {
            // See the following for styling hints:
            // https://help.github.com/articles/mapping-geojson-files-on-github#styling-features
            marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({
                'marker-color': '#CC0000'
            }));
        });
    })
    .addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured I could just set style parameters at any time. It seems odd that I have to wait for the layer to be loaded to do that. I also lose the styling when I load other geoJSON, which is unexpected. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the zipLayer after setting the style?

Comment: Good question: yes, just did. Doesn't work either. I must be doing something wrong, I'm just not seeing what.